making a serial number in assembly with reverse engineering
I have an assembly code that you should enter an input and after that with some operating on it, it makes a serial number when you enter a serial number as an input the congratulation message will show. till now I understand that it gets an input and the program XOR input with 504E4D41 if there result of them equal with 6DB278D8 the next step is xor between that result and again 504E4D41 but when I calculate it and enter it to input that's not correct. could you help me that in with part of this code there serial number is made? or where is my mistake in calculating of serial number

00401000 >/$ 55 PUSH EBP

00401001 |. 8BEC MOV EBP,ESP

00401003 |. 53 PUSH EBX

00401004 |. E8 05010000 CALL challeng.0040110E

00401009 |. 85C0 TEST EAX,EAX

0040100B |. 0F84 DA000000 JE challeng.004010EB

00401011 |. C705 08304000 >MOV DWORD PTR DS:[403008],challeng.<Modu>

0040101B |. C705 0C304000 >MOV DWORD PTR DS:[40300C],challeng.00400>

00401025 |. C705 10304000 >MOV DWORD PTR DS:[403010],400

0040102F |. C705 14304000 >MOV DWORD PTR DS:[403014],600

00401039 |. 68 19304000 PUSH challeng.00403019 ; /format = "**************************************************************

* AmnPardaz Reverse Engineering Challenge - Level 1 *

* *

* "...

0040103E |. E8 33020000 CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.printf> ; \printf

00401043 |. 83C4 04 ADD ESP,4

00401046 |. E8 3F010000 CALL challeng.0040118A

0040104B |. A1 2C204000 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[<&msvcrt._iob>]

00401050 |. 50 PUSH EAX ; /stream => OFFSET msvcrt._iob

00401051 |. 68 80000000 PUSH 80 ; |n = 80 (128.)

00401056 |. 8D05 6F314000 LEA EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[40316F] ; |

0040105C |. 50 PUSH EAX ; |s => challeng.0040316F

0040105D |. E8 0E020000 CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.fgets> ; \fgets

00401062 |. 83C4 0C ADD ESP,0C

00401065 |. 8035 6F314000 >XOR BYTE PTR DS:[40316F],0

0040106C |. 74 7D JE SHORT challeng.004010EB

0040106E |. 33C9 XOR ECX,ECX

00401070 |. 49 DEC ECX

00401071 |. 8D3D 6F314000 LEA EDI,DWORD PTR DS:[40316F]

00401077 |. B0 0A MOV AL,0A

00401079 |. F2:AE REPNE SCAS BYTE PTR ES:[EDI]

0040107B |. F7D1 NOT ECX

0040107D |. 49 DEC ECX

0040107E |. 6BC9 08 IMUL ECX,ECX,8

00401081 |. 83E9 40 SUB ECX,40

00401084 |. 75 65 JNZ SHORT challeng.004010EB

00401086 |. A1 6F314000 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[40316F]

0040108B 35 414D4E50 XOR EAX,504E4D41

00401090 75 59 JNZ SHORT challeng.004010EB

00401092 8D0D 6B314000 LEA ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[40316B]

00401098 8D1D 73314000 LEA EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[403173]

0040109E 8A43 02 MOV AL,BYTE PTR DS:[EBX+2]

004010A1 3001 XOR BYTE PTR DS:[ECX],AL

004010A3 8A03 MOV AL,BYTE PTR DS:[EBX]

004010A5 3041 03 XOR BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+3],AL

004010A8 8A43 01 MOV AL,BYTE PTR DS:[EBX+1]

004010AB 3041 02 XOR BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+2],AL

004010AE 8A43 03 MOV AL,BYTE PTR DS:[EBX+3]

004010B1 3041 01 XOR BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+1],AL

004010B4 A0 18304000 MOV AL,BYTE PTR DS:[403018]

004010B9 3001 XOR BYTE PTR DS:[ECX],AL

004010BB 3041 01 XOR BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+1],AL

004010BE 3041 02 XOR BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+2],AL

004010C1 3041 03 XOR BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+3],AL

004010C4 8B01 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]

004010C6 2D DB78B26D SUB EAX,6DB278DB

004010CB 75 1E JNZ SHORT challeng.004010EB

004010CD C705 67314000 >MOV DWORD PTR DS:[403167],504E4D41

004010D7 |. E8 4C010000 CALL challeng.00401228

004010DC |. 8D05 64424000 LEA EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[404264]

004010E2 |. 50 PUSH EAX ; /format => "p‚ÇM$*p’œ"

004010E3 |. E8 8E010000 CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.printf> ; \printf

004010E8 |. 83C4 04 ADD ESP,4

004010EB |> 5B POP EBX

004010EC |. 8BE5 MOV ESP,EBP

004010EE |. 5D POP EBP

004010EF \. C3 RETN

004010F0 CC INT3

004010F1 CC INT3

004010F2 CC INT3

004010F3 CC INT3

004010F4 CC INT3

004010F5 CC INT3

004010F6 CC INT3

004010F7 CC INT3

004010F8 CC INT3

004010F9 CC INT3

004010FA CC INT3

004010FB CC INT3

004010FC CC INT3

004010FD CC INT3

004010FE CC INT3

004010FF CC INT3

00401100 CC INT3

00401101 CC INT3

00401102 CC INT3

00401103 CC INT3

00401104 CC INT3

00401105 CC INT3

00401106 CC INT3

00401107 CC INT3

00401108 CC INT3

00401109 CC INT3

0040110A CC INT3

0040110B CC INT3

0040110C CC INT3

0040110D CC INT3

0040110E /$ 55 PUSH EBP

0040110F |. 8BEC MOV EBP,ESP

00401111 |. 56 PUSH ESI

00401112 |. 6A 00 PUSH 0 ; /pModule = NULL

00401114 |. FF15 1C204000 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&kernel32.GetModuleH>; \GetModuleHandleA

0040111A |. A3 00304000 MOV DWORD PTR DS:[403000],EAX

0040111F |. 8BF0 MOV ESI,EAX

00401121 |. 0FB706 MOVZX EAX,WORD PTR DS:[ESI]

00401124 |. 3D 4D5A0000 CMP EAX,5A4D

00401129 |. 75 30 JNZ SHORT challeng.0040115B

0040112B |. 8B46 3C MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+3C]

0040112E |. 8D3406 LEA ESI,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EAX]

00401131 |. 813E 50450000 CMP DWORD PTR DS:[ESI],4550

00401137 |. 75 22 JNZ SHORT challeng.0040115B

00401139 |. 66:817E 04 4C0>CMP WORD PTR DS:[ESI+4],14C

0040113F |. 75 1A JNZ SHORT challeng.0040115B

00401141 |. 6A 00 PUSH 0 ; /MaximumSize = 0

00401143 |. 68 00100000 PUSH 1000 ; |InitialSize = 1000 (4096.)

00401148 |. 6A 01 PUSH 1 ; |Flags = HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE

0040114A |. FF15 14204000 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&kernel32.HeapCreate>; \HeapCreate

00401150 |. 85C0 TEST EAX,EAX

00401152 |. 74 07 JE SHORT challeng.0040115B

00401154 |. A3 04304000 MOV DWORD PTR DS:[403004],EAX

00401159 |. EB 07 JMP SHORT challeng.00401162

0040115B |> 33C0 XOR EAX,EAX

0040115D |. 5E POP ESI

0040115E |. 8BE5 MOV ESP,EBP

00401160 |. 5D POP EBP

00401161 |. C3 RETN

00401162 |> B8 01000000 MOV EAX,1

00401167 |. 5E POP ESI

00401168 |. 8BE5 MOV ESP,EBP

0040116A |. 5D POP EBP

0040116B \. C3 RETN

0040116C CC INT3

0040116D CC INT3

0040116E CC INT3

0040116F CC INT3

00401170 CC INT3

00401171 CC INT3

00401172 CC INT3

00401173 CC INT3

00401174 CC INT3

00401175 CC INT3

00401176 CC INT3

00401177 CC INT3

00401178 CC INT3

00401179 CC INT3

0040117A CC INT3

0040117B CC INT3

0040117C CC INT3

0040117D CC INT3

0040117E CC INT3

0040117F CC INT3

00401180 CC INT3

00401181 CC INT3

00401182 CC INT3

00401183 CC INT3

00401184 CC INT3

00401185 CC INT3

00401186 CC INT3

00401187 CC INT3

00401188 CC INT3

00401189 CC INT3

0040118A /$ 55 PUSH EBP

0040118B |. 8BEC MOV EBP,ESP

0040118D |. 81EC 2C010000 SUB ESP,12C

00401193 |. 56 PUSH ESI

00401194 |. 57 PUSH EDI

00401195 |. 51 PUSH ECX

00401196 |. 53 PUSH EBX

00401197 |. 6A 00 PUSH 0 ; /ProcessID = 0

00401199 |. 6A 02 PUSH 2 ; |Flags = TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS

0040119B |. FF15 0C204000 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&kernel32.CreateTool>; \CreateToolhelp32Snapshot

004011A1 |. 85C0 TEST EAX,EAX

004011A3 |. 74 7B JE SHORT challeng.00401220

004011A5 |. 8945 FC MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],EAX

004011A8 |. 68 28010000 PUSH 128 ; /Length = 128 (296.)

004011AD |. 8D85 D4FEFFFF LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-12C] ; |

004011B3 |. 50 PUSH EAX ; |Destination

004011B4 |. FF15 10204000 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&kernel32.RtlZeroMem>; \RtlZeroMemory

004011BA |. C785 D4FEFFFF >MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-12C],128

004011C4 |. 8D85 D4FEFFFF LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-12C]

004011CA |. 50 PUSH EAX ; /pProcessentry

004011CB |. FF75 FC PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4] ; |hSnapshot

004011CE |. FF15 08204000 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&kernel32.Process32F>; \Process32First

004011D4 |. 48 DEC EAX

004011D5 |. 75 40 JNZ SHORT challeng.00401217

004011D7 |> 8B1D EF414000 /MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[4041EF]

004011DD |. 8D3D F3414000 |LEA EDI,DWORD PTR DS:[4041F3]

004011E3 |. 8DB5 F8FEFFFF |LEA ESI,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-108]

004011E9 |> 57 |/PUSH EDI ; /String2

004011EA |. 56 ||PUSH ESI ; |String1

004011EB |. FF15 18204000 ||CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&kernel32.lstrcmpi>; \lstrcmpiA

004011F1 |. 85C0 ||TEST EAX,EAX

004011F3 |. 75 07 ||JNZ SHORT challeng.004011FC

004011F5 |. 8005 18304000 >||ADD BYTE PTR DS:[403018],5

004011FC |> 33C0 ||XOR EAX,EAX

004011FE |> AE ||/SCAS BYTE PTR ES:[EDI]

004011FF |.^75 FD ||\JNZ SHORT challeng.004011FE

00401201 |. 4B ||DEC EBX

00401202 |.^75 E5 |\JNZ SHORT challeng.004011E9

00401204 |. 8D85 D4FEFFFF |LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-12C]

0040120A |. 50 |PUSH EAX ; /pProcessentry

0040120B |. FF75 FC |PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4] ; |hSnapshot

0040120E |. FF15 04204000 |CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&kernel32.Process32>; \Process32Next

00401214 |. 48 |DEC EAX

00401215 |.^74 C0 \JE SHORT challeng.004011D7

00401217 |> FF75 FC PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4] ; /hObject

0040121A |. FF15 00204000 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&kernel32.CloseHandl>; \CloseHandle

00401220 |> 5B POP EBX

00401221 |. 59 POP ECX

00401222 |. 5F POP EDI

00401223 |. 5E POP ESI

00401224 |. 8BE5 MOV ESP,EBP

00401226 |. 5D POP EBP

00401227 \. C3 RETN

00401228 /$ 56 PUSH ESI

00401229 |. 53 PUSH EBX

0040122A |. 51 PUSH ECX

0040122B |. 8B0D 74424000 MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[404274]

00401231 |. 8D35 64424000 LEA ESI,DWORD PTR DS:[404264]

00401237 |. 33DB XOR EBX,EBX

00401239 |> 8A83 67314000 /MOV AL,BYTE PTR DS:[EBX+403167]

0040123F |. 3006 |XOR BYTE PTR DS:[ESI],AL

00401241 |. 43 |INC EBX

00401242 |. 83FB 08 |CMP EBX,8

00401245 |. 75 02 |JNZ SHORT challeng.00401249

00401247 |. 33DB |XOR EBX,EBX

00401249 |> 46 |INC ESI

0040124A |. 49 |DEC ECX

0040124B |.^75 EC \JNZ SHORT challeng.00401239

0040124D |. 59 POP ECX

0040124E |. 5B POP EBX

0040124F |. 5E POP ESI

00401250 \. C3 RETN

00401251 CC INT3

00401252 CC INT3

00401253 CC INT3

00401254 CC INT3

00401255 CC INT3

00401256 CC INT3

00401257 CC INT3

00401258 CC INT3

00401259 CC INT3

0040125A CC INT3

0040125B CC INT3

0040125C CC INT3

0040125D CC INT3

0040125E CC INT3

0040125F CC INT3

00401260 CC INT3

00401261 CC INT3

00401262 CC INT3

00401263 CC INT3

00401264 CC INT3

00401265 CC INT3

00401266 CC INT3

00401267 CC INT3

00401268 CC INT3

00401269 CC INT3

0040126A CC INT3

0040126B CC INT3

0040126C CC INT3

0040126D CC INT3

0040126E CC INT3

0040126F CC INT3

00401270 $-FF25 28204000 JMP DWORD PTR DS:[<&msvcrt.fgets>] ; msvcrt.fgets

00401276 $-FF25 24204000 JMP DWORD PTR DS:[<&msvcrt.printf>] ; msvcrt.printf

0040127C 00 DB 00

